# Rails 3 empty field on submit displays multiple error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and currently learning about validations, so i have created a form within which i have a field named no (type integer), in the model for validation i have done something like this:

```
validates :no,
        :presence => true,
        :uniqueness => true,
        :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1, :less_than_or_equal_to => 99999 }
```

now when nothing is entered than two error messages are displayed

1]Noを入力してください。 -> please input the no.
2]Noは数値で入力してください。 -> please enter the number in integer only.

sorry abt the japanese stuff as my os is in japanese ;-)

what i need is that when the 'no' field is empty it should only display the error_message for that emptiness. Currently it is displaying error_message for both presence & numericality when the field is just empty.

I'm sorry if this is a really basic question I have tried searching for answers but I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your validation for numericality to only work when that field is present.

```
validates :no,
  :presence => true,
  :uniqueness => { :if => :no_is_present? },
  :numericality => {
    :only_integer => true,
    :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1,
    :less_than_or_equal_to => 99999,
    :if => :no_is_present?
  }

def no_is_present?
  no.present?
end
```

Comment: Hi jvnill thx for quick reply it has solved half of the prblm, nw on btn click when the field is empty it displays only the required err msg, but when i enter chars then 2 msgs [Enter only number] & [Record already exist] is displayed...prior to posting this question i had tried custom validation, while doin it i found out that characters sets the no attribute to 0 and i have a record 0 in db which is needed, cud u help me out with this..thanku

Comment: what do you want to display in that case?  can you update your question with a specific example?

Comment: As'no' is integer than it should only display err msg [Enter only number] why is it displaying [Record already exist] for chars

Comment: it's because the field is most probably an integer or decimal field. Rails typecasts the field to the data type that is in the database.  what you can do is add another check to on numericality which checks if `no` is a number.

Comment: Thx a lot for the help i've added an extra function as u said.